# SQL select query need task

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables city and house (foreign key to house), I need get result true if city's all houses has property has_door = true.
[image]

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select c.name, min(has_door) as all_houses_in_city_have_doors
from city c 
join house h on h.city_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.name
```

Comment: You missed the '_I need get result true if city's all houses has property has_door = true._'.

Comment: That is the `min(has_door)` part.

Comment: Yes, of course. Upvoted.